# Interpreting Stackdriver Metrics meaning "Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 240 seconds"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We are in process of identifying Stackdriver metrics

I am specifically looking at  GCP predefined metric **subscription/ack_message_count** with description Cumulative count of messages acknowledged by Acknowledge requests, grouped by delivery type. **Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 240 seconds.**

Can any one help me understand highlighted part, what does **Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 240 seconds.** mean

once i check this metric will it not able available for next 240 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: I think what it means is that the latency between getting a value and you being able to use that value (either for dashboarding or alerting) could be as long as 4 minutes (240 seconds).  Imagine you care if the ack count doesn't increase and you want to use this as an alert.  The message is warning you that the notification could be up to 4 minutes after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, the data is polled every 60 seconds but at the metrics creation the time until the data is polled would take up to 240 seconds. The BigQuery section makes this a bit clearer. Because the numbers are as such that it would not be feasible in an other context

Example: Scanned bytes. Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 21720 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

"Sampled every" refers to granularity. In this case, you'll get a data point for every minute.

"not visible" refers to freshness. In this case, the newest data point will describe the system as it was 4 minutes ago. Put another way, if you do something and watch the graphs you won't see the metric reflect the change for 4 minutes.